# Post Specific Uploader

Tags: uploads, media, filters

I have played around with filters for uploading files. The closest I have gotten is to have the files uploaded to the directory, but after the file uploads, I get a series of errors:
`Undefined index: post_id`
I think the issue is as simple as not having access to the current post id. I have tried `$wp_query->post->ID;` and `$post->ID` and neither seem to work.
These files would always be associated with a post.

The last iteration of the code I am using:

```
// filter for uploads
    function ml_media_upload_dir($upload) {

    $id = $_REQUEST['post_id'];
    $parent = get_post( $id )->post_parent;

        if (isset($_REQUEST['post_id'])) {
            $upload['path']    = "/foo/www/folder/blog/wp-content/uploads/" . $id;
            $upload['url']     = "http://foo.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/" . $id;
            $upload['basedir'] = "/foo/www/folder/blog/wp-content/uploads/" . $id;
            $upload['baseurl'] = "http://foo.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/" . $id;

            if (!file_exists("/foo/www/folder/blog/wp-content/uploads/" . $id)) {
                mkdir("/foo/www/folder/blog/wp-content/uploads/" . $id, 0777);
            }
        }


        return $upload;
    }
    add_filter('upload_dir', 'ml_media_upload_dir');
```

I even tried adding another 'insert media' link with the post_action=1 param  to test.
(`http://foo.com/blog/wp-admin/media-upload.php?post_id=571&TB_iframe=1&post_action=1&width=640&height=567`)

How can I ensure that if there is a post_id, that  the file gets loaded into the specific folder?

Any help..

cheers!
Bo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the argument is present, and if it isn't return the default value:

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['post_id']))
  return $upload;

// cast it to integer to avoid problems
$id = (int)$_REQUEST['post_id'];

...
```

Comment: sigh, in all the iterations, after a while I left that check out. It should've been there. **thanks**!!

Comment: Thanks, One Trick Pony! I was looking for a way to only show custom media fields added via `attachment_fields_to_edit` in WP 3.5 when they were attached to the post being viewed, and `$_REQUEST['post_id']` was what I needed since $GOBALS['post'] is not set at that point.