# Image not showing up in media loader success area - followup

Tags: urls, links, filters, uploads

This is part two to this question:
[Post Specific Uploader](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48014/post-specific-uploader/48015#48015)

I am using an upload filter to put files in a location based on `post_id`. Now when the file uploads, the URL path in the meta is wrong and the  image preview is broken (missing the `post_id`).

the URL shows as:
 `http://foo.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/icon_jpeg.png` 
but should (in this case) be:
`http://foo.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/571/icon_jpeg.png`

This part is truly magic to me. Should the path be correct if those were the value when the file was uploaded? Is there a query param I need to change?

Thanks for helping a WP noob!

Cheers.Bo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

untested, but it should work theoretically:

```
add_filter('get_attached_file', function($path, $file, $attachment_id){

  // get the post object of the current attachment
  $att = get_post($attachment_id);

  // prepend attachment post parent ID to the file name
  return substr_replace($path, "{$att->post_parent}/{$file}", -strlen($file));
});
```

---

Another filter, attempts to "fix" the path returned by WP's upload handler:

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload', function($results){
  global $post;

  if(empty($post))
    return $results;

  extract($results);

  $uploads = wp_upload_dir();

  $file = str_replace($uploads['basedir'], "{$uploads['basedir']}/{$post->ID}", $file);
  $url = str_replace($uploads['baseurl'], "{$uploads['baseurl']}/{$post->ID}", $url);

  return compact('file', 'url', 'type');
});
```

This will not work if the media uploader doesn't expose the current post inside the global $post variable.

Comment: Ill give it a shot! So it looks as if i am grabbing the post var in transit? Here is the odd thing, if i close the result window, and open it again, the preview path is right, and the image IS there!

Comment: before I give this a shot can you walk thru this or comment? does get_attached_file only affect the file path immediately after upload? .. sigh 15 rep to upvote...

Comment: That function should be called every time you request an image from an attachment. It will get the file name of the image (which is a meta value of the attachment), then it appends it to the wp upload path to generate the full image path. What function are you using to display these images?

Comment: it only needs to be fixed immediately after the upload. Right after I upload, the uploader shows the image and the path, but they are both wrong. BUT, if I close the media uploader window, then reopen it, the path and the thumbnail do appear. I guess I could strstr() for the presence of the post_id and if not there, then alter. I think my question is, why is it happening only immediately after the download. **Thanks for your help!**

Comment: This is because the uploader will update the current page based on the paths returned by the upload handler. I added another filter for that, it probably won't work though...

Comment: I will try it! Ill mark this as correct, programmatically it seems correct, but I will play with it and post the answer if it differs..